How to integrate Power BI's Q&A feature inside a Nextjs application
I want to integrate the feature of power BI of asking questions to the Database then returning visualizations into a Nextjs app. Is there a way to do that?
I know of the https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-client-react library in react, but can't seem to find a real example of the Q&A feature working inside a Nextjs app.
I want to be able to pass a Database with its schema, then ask questions based on the provided info. From my research, this is called a NLIDB (Natural Language Interface for Databases). According to some further research, this is exactly what power BI Q&A does. However, I have found it troublesome to find examples of codes that integrate this Q&A feature into a Nextjs app.
If there exist another tool better for creating this sort of application with Nextjs, please do point it out.
